# Responsive CarouFredSel carousel with fixed width items

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, carousel

I'm looking for the above, but all the examples I find for responsive CarouFredSel carousels show variable width items. I need my items to stay a certain width.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cffutdjt/7/

And here's the CarouFredSel initialisation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if ($("#trends").length >= 1) {
        $("#trends").carouFredSel({
            responsive: true,
            auto: false,
            items: {
                width: 245,
                visible: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 4
                }
            },
            scroll: {
                auto: true,
                items: 1,
                height: 'variable',
                easing: "linear",
                duration: 500
            },
            pagination: {
                container: '#controls'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any idea why it's ignoring my set item width? They should stay at 245px, no?

Sean

Comment: First off you've got some CSS which is overriding things and then you also set the carousel to `responsive:true` which I think will then also do some changes.  I have tried to change that on the fiddle but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: What CSS is overriding?

Comment: I guess you found the CSS as your edited fiddle is missing the offending CSS which was setting the width of `img` to `100%`

Comment: Yes I tidied the CSS but I don't see how it was offending as the problem still there. The widths are still variable.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had the same issue and the only solution i found was injecting a css inside the script, so i override the script's width like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
if ($("#trends").length >= 1) {
    $("#trends").carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        auto: false,
        items: {
            width: 245,
            visible: {
                min: 1,
                max: 4
            }
        },
        scroll: {
            auto: true,
            items: 1,
            height: 'variable',
            easing: "linear",
            duration: 500
        },
        pagination: {
            container: '#controls'
        }
    });
}
$('.list_carousel1 li').css({'width':'265px'});
});
```

as you can see here i fixed the li width to 265px. You cannot do this directly in your project CSS since the script executes After the CSS so for exemple if the width in your CSS is 300px and the script says 500px, so it will be 500px ! BUT if you inject your CSS directly in the script just after the execution it will be fine. the width proprety in items doesn't seem to work in CarouFredSel this why i had to do this workAround.
Hope this was helpful even after 2 years